# Meteor GridFS, CollectionFS - Download URLs for Files on Meteor 2.11 / Mongo 6 result in 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: mongodb, meteor, gridfs, collectionfs

After updating Meteor from 2.10 to 2.11 which includes Mongo 6
The download URLs from Files stored in the GridFS returning

```
503 - Service Unavailable
```

URL is still the same.

Packages in use:

```
cfs:access-point@0.1.49
cfs:base-package@0.0.30
cfs:collection@0.5.5
cfs:collection-filters@0.2.4
cfs:data-man@0.0.6
cfs:file@0.1.17
cfs:filesystem@0.1.2
cfs:gridfs@0.0.34
cfs:http-methods@0.0.32
cfs:http-publish@0.0.13
cfs:power-queue@0.9.11
cfs:reactive-list@0.0.9
cfs:reactive-property@0.0.4
cfs:standard-packages@0.5.10
cfs:storage-adapter@0.2.4
cfs:tempstore@0.1.6
cfs:upload-http@0.0.20
cfs:worker@0.1.5
```

Collection / Store:

```
const storeName = 'files';
const defaultStoreOptions = {
  beforeWrite: (fileObj) => {
    if (!fileObj.isImage()) {
      return {
        type: 'application/octet-stream',
      };
    }
    return {};
  },
};

const store = new FS.Store.GridFS(storeName, {
  ...defaultStoreOptions,
});

Files = new FS.Collection('files', {
  stores: [store],
});
```